# How can I get jq to pretty print json ordering keys alphabetically

Tags: json, jq

I use jq to pretty print very complicated json. then use diff to compare different version. Is there a way I can get jq to order the output alphabetically by keys?

faster xml object mappers have support for this

```
prettyPrintObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
prettyPrintObjectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true); //turn on
prettyPrintObjectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS, true);

String tmp1 = prettyPrintObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(myObject);
```

Kind regards

Andy

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As per the [manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/jq.1.html), use the `-S` flag to format the output like that:

> --sort-keys / -S:
>
> Output the fields of each object with the keys in sorted order.

Comment: $ jq -S "."  test.json