# SOLR order/display response fields list in specific way when JSON call?

Tags: indexing, solr, field, response

I have a question about SOLR response fields when **JSON** response format is obtained.
I have a Web service returning more than 20 fields and they are ordered by default as first the fields having data and after that all other fields.

My question is there a way to precise the order of the fields list, so that we obtain them always in same order ?

Example if I have the fields FIELD 1, FIELD 2, etc, I want that I preserve exactly this order and not FIELD 2, FIELD 1.

Thanks

Comment: Be aware that the JSON format does _not_ guarantee order for object properties after deserialization.

Comment: You can use [JSON sort-keys to sort keys in an order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38210345)

Answer (score -1):

yes you can precise the order editing the "data-config.xml" , here as you can see are declared all fields  and  on top are are the corresponding query , delta imports and full import . try to change the fields order in query and declaration in bottom,

example :

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="HttpDataSource" />
    <document>
            <entity name="slashdot"
                    pk="link"
                    url="http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot"
                    processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
                    forEach="/RDF/channel | /RDF/item"
                    transformer="DateFormatTransformer">

                    <field column="source"       xpath="/RDF/channel/title"   commonField="true" />
                    <field column="source-link"  xpath="/RDF/channel/link"    commonField="true" />
                    <field column="subject"      xpath="/RDF/channel/subject" commonField="true" />

                    <field column="title"        xpath="/RDF/item/title" />
                    <field column="link"         xpath="/RDF/item/link" />
                    <field column="description"  xpath="/RDF/item/description" />
                    <field column="creator"      xpath="/RDF/item/creator" />
                    <field column="item-subject" xpath="/RDF/item/subject" />

                    <field column="slash-department" xpath="/RDF/item/department" />
                    <field column="slash-section"    xpath="/RDF/item/section" />
                    <field column="slash-comments"   xpath="/RDF/item/comments" />
                    <field column="date" xpath="/RDF/item/date" dateTimeFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss" />
            </entity>
    </document>
```

Comment: I must to add a specifique transformer ? Actually I use RegexTransformer. The order of the fields in data-config is not take in count now.

Comment: in Answer its a example , the field are ordered manually , for more ---- https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler

Comment: My documents are coming from the database. So I don't know if I can apply the same principe.

Comment: but you are using SOLR  conf to index results ?  search the file 'data-config.xml'

Comment: Yes, I use the data-config.xml to fill the fields, but the order of this fields seems to be not important, because the JSON response is completely different.

Comment: you should check and 'schema.xml' , hope is useful

Comment: The schema.xm has the same order as my data-config.xml file

Comment: see -- https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/response-writers.html , also  you can change order  using  coding  , converting to Class and change the order of fields ,,